# Data Access Only Works if Print Before

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of data that was read from a CSV file. I loop through the data and assign some elements of each row to a variable. The issue I'm running into is that unless I print the data before the line that assigns the elements of the data, I get an IndexError:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So this doesn't work:

```
for row in data:
    meter_name = str(row[1])+str(row[4])
```

But this **does** work:

```
for row in data:
    print row
    meter_name = str(row[1])+str(row[4])
```

And this works:

```
for row in data:
    print len(row)
    meter_name = str(row[1])+str(row[4])
```

I'm using python 2.7 pywin32 build 219 in Windows 7 64 bit. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing this `meter_name = str(row[1])+str(row[4])` 
to this 
`meter_name = str(row[1 - 1])+str(row[4 - 1])`

Comment: There must be something else you're not showing. Printing a line will have no effect on whether you get an indexing exception.

Comment: There's likely something more going on than what we can see here. Can you turn this into a standalone program that shows this issue, including a relevant (but small) data file (small enough so you can just copy-paste the data into the question)? For starters, we don't even know how the CSV was read, and thus what type of object `data` is.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with printing or not printing, obviously. Please post the minimal code (and data) required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I agree that print definitely shouldn't affect the indexing. That's why I'm puzzled. I'm writing a minimal working example to post.

Comment: @PProteus If it is behaving exactly as you've described, it's more likely an IDE problem than a problem with the code. Trying restarting the IDE/clearing its cache. I've had IDEs claim weird errors like this seemingly due to caching problems.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. The problem was occurring in the last three lines of a 500,000+ row data file. When I included the print statements, it slowed the program down sufficiently such that it never reached the end of the file before I stopped it, assuming that it had run through correctly.